# How to delete a certain row if it contains a particular string in it using python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have to create a clean list wherein names with 'Trust' or 'Trustee' in rows get deleted.

I'm using the following code but i'm not getting the desired result ?

```
df_clean = df[~df['Row Labels'].str.contains('trusteeship')]
```

eg : if the 'Row Labels' contains a row with ABC Trust or XYTrusteeshipZ, then the whole row should get deleted.

[df_clean = df[~df['Row Labels'].str.contains('Trust')]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKEa5.png)

[df_clean = df[~df['Row Labels'].str.lower().str.contains('trust')]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGp1X.png)

Comment: Use `df_clean = df[~df['Row Labels'].str.contains('Trust')]`

Comment: @jezrael thanks but i have already tried it.. didn't help.. i'l add the screenshot for the same

Comment: `df_clean = df[~df['Row Labels'].str.lower().str.contains('trust')]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match with `case=False` parameter for ignore lower/uppercase characters:

```
df_clean = df[~df['Row Labels'].str.contains('trust', case=False)]
```

Or first convert values to lowercase like mentioned @anon01 in comments:

```
df_clean = df[~df['Row Labels'].str.lower().str.contains('trust')]
```

Comment: i tried this .. provided a snippet for the same as well

Comment: df_clean = df[~df['Row Labels'].str.contains('trust', case=False)]

this worked.. thanks buddy @jezrael